# ValueError: Shape of passed values is blah, indices imply blah

Tags: python, pandas, list, pos-tagger, flair

I try to do POS-Tagging to a list of sentences in Bahasa Indonesia with Flair https://github.com/flairNLP/flair

The result is a `list`, the name is `pos`:

```
['Sejarah <NOUN> perkembangan <NOUN> ilmu <NOUN> ekonomi <NOUN> Adam <PROPN> Smith <PROPN> sering <ADV> disebut <VERB> sebagai <ADP> yang <PRON> pertama <NUM> mengembangkan <VERB> ilmu <NOUN> ekonomi <NOUN> pada <ADP> abad <NOUN> 18 <NUM> sebagai <ADP> satu <DET> cabang <NOUN> tersiri <NOUN> dalam <ADP> ilmu <NOUN> pengetahuan <NOUN>', 'Melalui <ADP> karya <NOUN> besarnya <NOUN> General <PROPN> Theory <PROPN> Employment <PROPN> Interest <PROPN> and <PROPN> Money <PROPN> yang <PRON> menyatakan <VERB> bahwa <SCONJ> pasar <NOUN> tidak <PART> selalu <ADV> mampu <ADV> menciptakan <VERB> keseimbangan <NOUN> dan <CCONJ> karena <SCONJ> itu <DET> intervensi <NOUN> pemerintah <NOUN> harus <ADV> dilakukan <VERB> agar <SCONJ> distribusi <NOUN> ber <VERB> daya <NOUN> mencapai <VERB> sasarannya <NOUN>']
```

I want to convert that list to be dataframe, like this:

```
                     Text      Label
0                 Sejarah     NOUN
1            perkembangan     NOUN
2                    ilmu     NOUN
3                 ekonomi     NOUN
4                    Adam     PROPN
5                   Smith     PROPN
6                  sering     ADV
7                 disebut     VERB
8                 sebagai     ADP 
9                    yang     PRON 
10                pertama     NUM
...                   ...     ...
...                   ...     ...
```

I have tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pos, columns=['Text', 'Label'])
```

But I got this error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6921, 1), indices imply (6921, 2)
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
# convert string to list
d = d[0].split()

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(d[::2], d[1::2]), columns=['Text', 'Label']) 

# modify label col
df['Label'] = df['Label'].str.replace('\W','').str.strip()

print(df)

             Text  Label
0         Sejarah   NOUN
1    perkembangan   NOUN
2            ilmu   NOUN
3         ekonomi   NOUN
4            Adam  PROPN
5           Smith  PROPN
6          sering    ADV
7         disebut   VERB
8         sebagai    ADP
9            yang   PRON
10        pertama    NUM
11  mengembangkan   VERB
12           ilmu   NOUN
13        ekonomi   NOUN
14           pada    ADP
15           abad   NOUN
16             18    NUM
17        sebagai    ADP
18           satu    DET
19         cabang   NOUN
20        tersiri   NOUN
21          dalam    ADP
22           ilmu   NOUN
23    pengetahuan   NOUN
```

---

For a list of strings, you can do:

```
# d is list of strings
d = [x.split() for x in d]

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(zip(x[::2], x[1::2]), columns=['Text', 'Label']) for x in d], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: if I want to process the whole list? not only d[0]?